# Implementing IEdmStrLst5 and IEdmPos5 - SOLIDWORKS PDM API

Tags: c#, solidworks

So the SOLIDWORKS PDM API implements a weird way of storing an array of string. Instead of storing it in a plain simple string[], there is this interface called [IEdmStr5](http://help.solidworks.com/2016/english/api/epdmapi/EPDM.Interop.epdm~EPDM.Interop.epdm.IEdmStrLst5.html) that is used to store a list of an arbitary string. I don't know the design reason behind this but my guess is related to intrinsics of the Component Object Model. Along with the [IEdmPos5](http://help.solidworks.com/2015/english/api/epdmapi/epdm.interop.epdm~epdm.interop.epdm.iedmpos5.html) interface, you can traverse the list of string. Here's an example below that traverse a list of configuration names:

```
private bool IsConfigInList(IEdmStrLst5 ConfigNames, string ConfigName)
    {
        bool functionReturnValue = false;
        functionReturnValue = false;
        try
        {
            string CurConfig = null;
            IEdmPos5 Pos = ConfigNames.GetHeadPosition();
            while (!Pos.IsNull)
            {
                CurConfig = ConfigNames.GetNext(Pos);
                if (CurConfig == ConfigName)
                {
                    functionReturnValue = true;
                    break; 
                }
            }
            return functionReturnValue;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox("HRESULT = 0x" + ex.ErrorCode.ToString("X") + Constants.vbCrLf + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Interaction.MsgBox(ex.Message);
        }
        return functionReturnValue;
    }
```

I am attempting to use these interface to mock them in my unit tests. Here is my attempt:

```
        // test
        public static void PrintmEdmStrLst5_Test()
        {

            var mStrList = new CADSharpTools.PDM.Testing.mEdmStrLst5(new string[] { "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3" });
            var mPos = mStrList.GetHeadPosition();
            while (mPos.IsNull == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mStrList.GetNext(mPos));

            }
        }

public class mEdmPos5 : IEdmPos5
    {
        int pos = -1; 

        public int GetIndex()
        {
            return pos; 
        }

        public mEdmPos5(int Pos)
        {
            pos = (int)Pos;
        }

        public IEdmPos5 Clone()
        {
            return new mEdmPos5(this.pos);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets whether the position in the sequence is null or not.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsNull =>  this.pos <= -1 ? true : false ;
    }
    public class mEdmStrLst5 : IEdmStrLst5
    {
        mEdmPos5 currentPosition = default(mEdmPos5);
        int counter = 0;
        int count = 0;
        List<string> innerList = new List<string>();
        List<mEdmPos5> innerPositions = new List<mEdmPos5>();

        public mEdmStrLst5(string[] arr)
        {
            innerList.AddRange(arr);
            count = arr.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                innerPositions.Add(new mEdmPos5(i));
            }


        }

        public void AddTail(string bsString)
        {
            innerList.Add(bsString);
            count = innerList.Count;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the first position. Calling this method will reset the counter to 0.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public IEdmPos5 GetHeadPosition()
        {
            currentPosition = innerPositions[0];
            counter = 0;
            return currentPosition;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the next str in the list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="poPos"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GetNext(IEdmPos5 poPos)
        {
            var clonedPosition = currentPosition.Clone(); 
            if (counter == innerList.Count-1)
            {
                currentPosition = new mEdmPos5(-1);
                poPos = currentPosition;
                return null; 
            }
            counter = counter + 1;
            currentPosition = innerPositions[counter];
            poPos = currentPosition;
            return innerList[(clonedPosition as mEdmPos5).GetIndex()];

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether the string list is empty or not.
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsEmpty => innerList.Count == 0 ? true : false;


        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the size of the list.
        /// </summary>
        public int Count => innerList.Count;
    }
```

All of the code above is in C#. My struggle seems to be around the GetNext(). It seems to be that mPos should be passed around as reference, otherwise, how is it possible to iterate through?

Below is the definition of the two interfaces:

```
public interface IEdmPos5
    {
        [DispId(2)]
        IEdmPos5 Clone();

        [DispId(1)]
        bool IsNull { get; }
    }
public interface IEdmStrLst5
    {
        [DispId(3)]
        void AddTail(string bsString);
        [DispId(4)]
        IEdmPos5 GetHeadPosition();
        [DispId(5)]
        string GetNext(IEdmPos5 poPos);

        [DispId(1)]
        bool IsEmpty { get; }
        [DispId(2)]
        int Count { get; }
    }
```

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it around IEnumerator as IEdmPos5 represents an enumerator

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEdmStrLst5 strLst = new EdmStrLstWrapper(new List<string>(new string[] { "A", "B", "C" }));

        var pos = strLst.GetHeadPosition();
        while (!pos.IsNull)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(strLst.GetNext(pos));
        }
    }
}

public class EdmStrLstWrapper : IEdmStrLst5
{
    private readonly List<string> m_List;

    public EdmStrLstWrapper(List<string> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(list));
        }

        m_List = list;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return m_List.Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return m_List.Count == 0;
        }
    }

    public void AddTail(string bsString)
    {
        m_List.Add(bsString);
    }

    public IEdmPos5 GetHeadPosition()
    {
        var pos = new EdmPosWrapper(m_List.GetEnumerator());
        pos.MoveNext();

        return pos;
    }

    public string GetNext(IEdmPos5 poPos)
    {
        if (poPos is EdmPosWrapper)
        {
            var val = (poPos as EdmPosWrapper).Current;
            (poPos as EdmPosWrapper).MoveNext();
            return val;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}

public class EdmPosWrapper : IEdmPos5
{
    private readonly IEnumerator m_Enumerator;

    private bool m_IsLast;

    public EdmPosWrapper(IEnumerator enumerator)
    {
        m_Enumerator = enumerator;
    }

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            return m_IsLast;
        }
    }

    public IEdmPos5 Clone()
    {
        return new EdmPosWrapper(m_Enumerator);
    }

    internal string Current
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Enumerator.Current as string;
        }
    }

    internal void MoveNext()
    {
        m_IsLast = !m_Enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense to implement the IEnumerator with the IEdmPos5!